# Creating custom scrollspy like bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am trying to create bootstrap like scrollspy.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).scroll(function(e){
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      var chapterpos1 = $("#chapter1").offset().top;
      var chapterpos2 = $("#chapter2").offset().top;
      if(chapterpos1 < scroll){
         $(".anchortag").removeClass("active");
         $("#box").find("[href='#chapter1']").addClass("active");
      }
      if(chapterpos2 < scroll){
         $(".anchortag").removeClass("active");
         $("#box").find("[href='#chapter2']").addClass("active");
      }

  });
});
```

This is my code. It works but how to make it dynamic if I don't the how many ids would be there in run time. Now I had implement for `#chapter1` and `#chapter2`. But how make it dynamic for 20 chapters like this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Select all chapters using attribute-starts-with selector (`[attribute^=value]`) and run a function that does what you need on each chapter you have found.

```
$(function(){
   $(window).scroll(function(e){
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

      $('.anchortag.active').removeClass('active');

      $('[id^=chapter]').each(function(_, chapter) {
          var id = chapter.id;

          if($(chapter).offset().top < scroll) {
             $('#box .anchortag[href=\'#' + id + '\']').addClass('active'); 
          }
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you it worked after small modification. I will post correct answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer:

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(e){
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  $('.anchortag.active').removeClass('active');

  $('[id^=chapter]').each(function(_, chapter) {
      var id = chapter.id;

      if($("#"+id).offset().top < scroll) {
         $('#box .anchortag).removeClass('active'); 
         $('#box .anchortag[href=\'#' + id + '\']').addClass('active'); 
      }
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: You don't need to requery the DOM. `chapter` is already the element you'll get by its id. IDs must be unique within the documents.
And you are removing class `active` multiple times. Why?

Comment: When I alert `chapter`, it returns `HTML DOMDOCUMENT` and I removed active class multiple times because only the list of specific position needs to get active class not all the list that has scroll position greater than the ids.

Comment: "When I alert chapter, it returns HTML DOMDOCUMENT" this is impossible. Are you getting correct ids, right? If yes `chapter` should be exactly the same element you gonna find using `$('#' + id)`. Again because ids **must be unique**. And if you need to highlight only the last chapter which offset top is smaller than `scroll` you could simply store its id in some outer variable and set the corresponding link to be active after the loop.